# Does the integral $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}\ln(1+\sqrt x)} dx$ converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

Does the integral

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}\ln(1+\sqrt x)} dx$$

converge?

It's easy to check that  $\int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}\ln(1+\sqrt x)} dx$ does converge, but I couldn't find the right method for either proving or disproving that  $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}\ln(1+\sqrt x)} dx$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We might check some equivalent for $x\mapsto \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2 \ln(1+\sqrt{x})}$ near zero.

hint: $$ \ln(1+x) = x + o(x)$$

Comment: the first thing I tried is: since $\ln (1+\sqrt x)<\sqrt x$, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}<\frac{1}{\ln (1+\sqrt x)}$, but it's not valid the use the comparsion test like that.

Comment: @gbi1977 $$\frac{\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}\le \log(1+\sqrt x)\le \sqrt x$$

Comment: @gbi1977 the inequality is true (out of zero) but is not useful to prove the convergence

Comment: $\frac{1}{log(1+\sqrt{x})} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $]0,1]$

Comment: @MarkViola I was not familiar with the left side inequality... thanks

Comment: @A.MONNET where did you derive that?

Comment: @gbi1977 See [This Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), which develops the left side estimate.  And for $x\in (0,1)$, we see that since $1+\sqrt x\le 2$, $\frac{1}{\log(1+\sqrt x)}\le \frac{1+\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}\le  \frac2{\sqrt x}$ as A. Monnet commented.

Comment: If you don't like the 2, just put any constant $c>0$ and study the function 
$f(x) := c\log(1+\sqrt{x}) - \sqrt{x}$ on $]0,1]$ then choose $c$ to get the good inequality on $]0,1]$